# Rewrite Specific Querystring URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Lets say I have a URL as follows:
http://www.testing.com/?id=1234

I want to take that specific URL and specific querystring and 301 redirect ONLY it with a RewriteRule.  So, http://www.testing.com/?id=12345 would not be redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1234$
RewriteRule (.*) /some/newurl [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason this results in a redirect loop

Comment: Actually I figured it out :)  RewriteRule (.*) /some/newurl/? [R=301,L] - All it needs is that question mark added to the RewriteRule line.  Thanks!